# What is a resource.cgn file used for in a Payment Gateway and what program can open it to see its content?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I have recently integrated a Payment Gateway to an e-commerce website (done first time).Presently during the tests, the website shows an error that:
Error: Unable to Open [https:/www.OUrwebiste.com/PG/resource.cgn]. All other PHP pages that come along with a Payment Gateway work fine except this file.

Trying to understand the cause behind the error but was not able to find much information elsewhere to solve this issue.

Would be thankful for the help

Comment: Seems like a question for the service provider. We don't even know which service you're using.

Comment: If a third party library complains about not being able to open a specific file, I would still recommend that you contact the service providers. It they need that file, it should come from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zip and the XML functionality weren't enabled on the server. So installed them and secondly created a folder as Resource and put the resource.cgn file inside it.

And mentioned the path where the resource path was needed as:

'server/PGFolder/Resource/'

instead of

'server/PGFolder/Resource/resource.cgn' or 'server/PGFolder/resource.cgn' in case the Resource folder is not created

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this file/folder has read and write access. Because process generates temp *.cgz file in the same folder. Hope this will help.

Comment: Do you use any third party library such as Ionic.zip? As Magnus already said.

Comment: Have you succeeded? It would help if you can post some stack info. Also, are you sure you have read, write access for appropriate user - account under which your web server process is accessing resources?